Cardinality of the set of functions defined on a finite set .
If $F$ be the set of all functions defined on $I_n =\{ 1 , 2 , 3 ,..., n\} , n\in \mathbb{N}  $ with range $B\subseteq I^+$( set of positive integers ) . Then
(a) $F$ is countable
(b) $F$ is uncountable .
(c) $F$ is infinite .
(d) $F$ is countable if $B$ is finite .
My attempt :-  Let $Y\subseteq B$
If $Range(f)=Y$, then
$|Y|=|f(I_n)|\le |I_n| =n  $
So for any $Y \subseteq B, s.t |Y| \le n$
Let $F(Y)=\{ f\in F | Range(f)=Y\} $
Then $|F(Y)|$ is finite and $F=\cup\{ F(Y) | Y \subseteq B ,|Y| \le n \}    $ .
As the set of all finite subsets of $B$ is countable and countable union of finite sets is countable , so $F$ is countable.
I request you to cross check my proof and suggest any better alternatives. Thanks .

One way is to induct on $n$ and use a diagonal argument in the inductive step.

@Porky I think $n$ is fixed .

Suppose you were free to define one of the various $f \in F$. Then how many choices would you have for $f(1)$?

$n$ is not fixed. It is arbitrary. The question covers all possible values of $n$. And even if it didn't, you would still be free to consider the case of an arbitrary $n$ and use induction to prove the result in general. Then the more limited case of the problem would still follow. However, your approach also works, so there is no need to use induction instead.
